# Octopus Deploy cannot find namespace in transform file

Tags: config, configuration-files, octopus-deploy, config-transformation

Have been trying to apply a transformation to one of my config files in Visual Studio 2010

The target file starts like this:

forms.config

```
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
        <sitecore> 
           <formsDataProvider type="Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataProviders.WFMDataProvider,Sitecore.Forms.Core">
             <param desc="connection string">connection string goes here</param>
           </formsDataProvider>
```

...

The transformation file is as follows:

forms.Staging.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- For more information on using transformations 
 see the web.config examples at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=214134. -->
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <sitecore>
    <formsDataProvider type="Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataProviders.WFMDataProvider,Sitecore.Forms.Core">
      <param desc="connection string" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(desc)">connection string for staging goes here</param>
    </formsDataProvider>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

When the staging build runs on Octopus this is what's in the log:

```
DEBUG  [XML Transformation] The expected namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform was not found in the transform file.
```

Have tried to remove the other xmlns attributes to no avail.

Said namespace is clearly on the transform file as an attribute in the configuration node. We have numerous other such files and transformations are applied fine. The Build Action for all transform files is set to Content.

Not sure if we can make Octopus log such messages as errors instead of Debug though.

Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be trying to apply your *forms.config* as a transformation file instead of a target.

What do you have specified in the deployment step's *Additional Transforms*? Did you accidentally include *forms.config* itself?

Comment: In the deployment log, forms.config is listed as a target file.

Octopus complains immediately after the "Applying forms.Staging.config transform file..." message.

Comment: Someone else had similar trouble with SiteCore and config transforms for non-Debug|Release .config files. Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9592018/1077279) your problem.